# Retain positions after pasting UIImageViews in new UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview

I made a prototype for an app, just as a proof of concept to test whether the functionality is working properly or not. Now that I am satisfied with the working functionality, I want to paste the images I placed in a `UIView` into a `UIScrollView`, so that I can show data in different pages. But, as I select the elements and paste it in a `scrollview`, all the positions are lost, and I have to manually place the elements in the interface builder.

Check out this image, I have these many elements that I need to paste inside the `UIScrollView`.

[image]

Is there a better way of doing this? or do I have to manually place the elements in positions I want?

Thanks!

Comment: This is ridiculous.  You know IB isn't the only way to set up interfaces, right?

Comment: Hmmm.. Your comment makes me think that I have overlooked something very simple. Help me out here, if I create instance of UIScrollView and call addSubView method, will it place in the exact same position? I haven't tried this yet, and will be trying it out now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid the headache of repostioning of controls in IB, then try the following option

1) Take one more `UIView`.

2) Add the `UIScrollView` into the `UIView`.

3) Add your current `UIView`(view which you shown in question) into the `UIScrollView`.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks I will try this and let you know.
Edit: Just Brilliant. Saved me a lot of time! Thank you for the simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

Select all your children, then Menu/editor/embed in scroll view.
Et voilà !